# PHP Fatal Error and Smarty Exception

Tags: php, smarty

We have a website running on Windows 7/IIS 7 using PHP and Smarty templates. The site is working fine in our local system but the same is not working in customer's machine. They are getting one strange exception in php crashed error log:`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 'Syntax Error in template &quot;templates\base\rp_debug.tpl&quot;  on line 37 &quot;_smarty_console.document.write(&amp;quot;&amp;lt;`

The code should be like this:

```
        _smarty_console.document.write("<
```

My question why " and < symbols are translated to &quot;&lt;?
Are there any settings in IIS that is blocking to not to prit HTML entities?

Comment: You want to kwnow the reason for the error on the template or just why the error message doesn't looks fine in screen?

Comment: I want to know the reason for the error. This error was not coming when we use Smarty version 2. The error came after upgrading Smarty from 2 to 3

Comment: well, then you'll have to show us line 37 (and surrounding) of your rp_debug.tpl file

Comment: _smarty_console.document.write("<tr bgcolor={if $debug[debug_line].type eq $smarty.const.DEBUG_MSG_TYPE_ERR}$ffff00{else}{if $debug[debug_line].type eq $smarty.const.DEBUG_MSG_TYPE_TODO}$ffffcc{else}{if %debug_line.index% is even}#eeeeee{else}#fafafa{/if}{/if}{/if}>");

Comment: @Borgtex Above code is at line 37

Comment: @Borgtex Please let me know how to attach a file or file contents to the site so that you can have a look at it. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: You can edit your original post and put the code there. As for the problem, still difficult to know, can you try to replace the line you posted by just _smarty_console.document.write("<tr>") to see if it works?